# Vue3 CoreUI CMultiSelect submitting unintentionally when 'Select all options' is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multi-select, core-ui

I'm fairly new to coding in Vue.js (3) and the project I have stepped into uses CoreUI for Vue as its main framework for forms and displays. I'm not sure if this is a bug in the CoreUI CMultiSelect itself, but when a user clicks **'Select all options'** in one of the form dropdowns, the form automatically submits before the user can fill out the rest/submit it for themselves. I'm especially confused because even when I disconnect the component from the custom `@change` (I just deleted the line) defined to save their selection, it still demonstrates the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Side note: I am also unfamiliar how to disable the select-all option, though it mentions this is possible in the [CoreUI Vue MultiSelect Documentation](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/forms/multi-select.html). I set `select-all="false"` within the component to no avail. If this is what I have to do for the time being until I figure this out, I would appreciate guidance on how to do so as well.

Here are the component and selection options:

```html
<CMultiSelect
  placeholder="Application Types"
  :options="battery_application_choices"
  @change="batteryappChanged($event)"
>

<!-- inside data() -->
battery_application_choices: [
  { text: 'Demand Reduction', value: 'Demand Reduction' },
  { text: 'Energy Arbitrage', value: 'Energy Arbitrage' },
  { text: 'Frequency Response', value: 'Frequency Response' },
  { text: 'Microgrid Component', value: 'Microgrid Component' },
  { text: 'Other', value: 'Other' },
  { text: 'Solar / Storage', value: 'Solar / Storage' },
  { text: 'UPS', value: 'UPS' },
],
```

[Select All Bug. I am not performing any other action besides clicking the 'Select all options' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgMiT.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer from myself since that's how coding is sometimes.

###### 1) Temporary Fix

I found how to implement my temporary fix, where I needed to type `:select-all="false"` with a colon to bind it instead of `select-all="false"`. For newbies like me, `:` is short for `v-bind` in Vue, which binds data to components so that when the data changes, the state of the app changes to reflect it.

###### Several days later...

###### 2) Robust Fix

In order to describe the robust solution to this problem, I will be outlining what I learned about JS events and how Vue handles watching them and their propagation. I will also be covering a bit of how Vue uses what you write to generate HTML code, specifically how the CoreUI multiselect component generates HTML elements like `<select>` and `<options>`.

What was causing the error was the fact that the `<CMultiSelect>` was nested in a parent `<CForm>`. This in itself is not bad practice, and is even practical given that some forms should have multiple selection fields alongside their other form fields. However, a problem arose when a user clicked the 'Select all options' button. This is because putting a `<CMultiSelect>` into your code instructs Vue to compose a collection of elements at runtime that are abstracted away from you, the developer. Vue generates a `<select>` block that contains an `<option>` element for each option that you bind to the `<CMultiSelect>`. It also generates a 'Select all options' `<button>` that for some reason can produce a `SubmitEvent`. When this event is produced, it propagates upward since it was not stopped with `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`. It gets caught by the submission watcher of the parent `<CForm>` and triggered the custom form submission in my project. This behavior was also caused by the small `x` buttons to delete tags from the multiselect view, but I did not look into the generated code with `console.log()`s enough to figure out why.

I was able to fix this problem by checking the `submitter` property of `event`.

> Side note: I would recommend doing a quick `console.log(event)` in any event handler methods that you are having trouble with, since events are much more complex than I thought and you will be able to see properties that can be of use to you.

`event.submitter` is a property of submit events, and returns the HTML element that generated that particular submission. In my case, it returned the 'submit(?)' button of the `<CMultiSelect>` which was of the form `<button ...>Select all options</button>`. I then accessed just the contents with `event.submitter.innerHTML` (which produced just `Select all options`) and if it matched this content, do nothing. This could also be used for a form with multiple submission buttons that trigger different types of submission (perhaps alternate processing of user data), because it allows you to tell where the event is coming from.

###### For example, the below form...

```
<form @submit.prevent="customHandler($event)">
    <button type='submit'>Save</button>
    <button type='submit'>Change</button>
</form>
```

###### ...Could have the following control logic in its handler method:

```
customHandler(event) {
    if (event.submitter.innerHTML == 'Save') {
        // Save user data
    } else if (event.submitter.innerHTML == 'Change') {
        // Change user data in different way than 'Save'
    } else {
        // Do nothing
        // The CMultiSelect's 'Select all options' event will fall here
    } 
}
```

###### What did we learn?

Since this issue took about 3 cumulative workdays out of my schedule I figured the post I made about it should carry the same weight. I know this is overkill but if even one other developer can avoid the same problem then it'll have been more than worth it. I would say I learned that JavaScript is so much more complicated than I thought imaginable, yet frustratingly stupid at the same time, but that would mean that I didn't know that before...

Comment: javascript is OK. the frameworks are stupid/complicated and badly documented